# Iterating through list of names and using min/max values to create new list

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something pretty basic.  I have a tab-delimited text file with 2 rows, Date and Name. Date is in Excel number format.  Here's an example...

```
Bill to Name    Date
James Doe       41929
Jane Doe        41852
Adam Adamson    42244
Adam Adamson    41529
```

What I need to do is iterate through the list of names, and find the difference between the smallest and the largest dates for each person, and output that to another list.  The output list should look similar to the input list above, except there will only be one of each name and the number will be smaller.  Not every person has more than one date, some names only have one and some names have 30.  I've pretty much only gotten through feeding the file in.

```
input_dir = "C:\\Users\\Intern\\Documents\\"
data_file = "Python.txt"
output_dir = "C:\\Users\\Intern\\Documents\\"
output_file_all = "Tenure.txt"

#testing file input
with open(input_dir + data_file,'r') as ifile :
    for idx, row in enumerate(ifile.readlines()) :
        print(row)
        if idx > 0 :
            break
```

Which works fine, but loops confuse me quite a bit. I'm assuming it would be something along the lines of "for each Name in ifile, Tenure = max(date)-min(date)", but I don't think that would iterate correctly.

Comment: The loop will iterate through each line in the file. Inside loop, you will have to segregate date and name, prepare separate lists for both of them and get the min of date for each person from it. I hope, I'm clear to you.

Comment: What happens if a person only have one date? The result list should have a corresponding 0 or should it be the same value in the given .csv?

Comment: So essentially it will be pulling all the lines in the main list that have the same name into their own list, and then finding the min/max from that list, subtracting max-min, and then putting that information in a new list?  If they have the same date then they would just be a 0 for the difference.  Trying to visualize that in code makes my head spin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`csv module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) will help in the future if the input file structure gets more complex. Dictionary seems the right data structure in this problem. Defaultdict is saving us from writing a few more lines.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict( list )

input_file = 'a.csv'
output_file = 'b.csv'

with open( input_file, 'rb' ) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header
    for row in reader:
        d[ row[0] ].append( int(row[1]) )

with open( output_file, 'wb' ) as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for key, value in d.items():
        writer.writerow( [key, max(value) - min(value)] )
```

which gives the output as **"b.csv"**:

```
Jane Doe        0
James Doe       0
Adam Adamson    715
```

Comment: I put in that code, had to change 'rb' to 'r', kept getting an "iterator should return strings, not bytes" error, which that fixed.  Now it's giving me an "IndexError: list index out of range" pointed at "   d[ row[0] ].append( int(row[1]) )" when I try to run it with my file.  I can't figure how to make my comments look like code, sorry.

Comment: I guess the problem might be because in your input file there may be lines which does not have any tabs, hence, `csv reader` is having problem to parse. Can you check the input file and make sure everything seems correct, i.e., every line has a tab seperated two columns?

Comment: That worked like a charm, for whatever reason the first line of data in my file had an extra space in it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you could do it very easy with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Bill to Name': ['James Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Adam Adamson', 'Adam Adamson'], 'Date': [41929, 41852, 42244, 41529]})

print(df)
   Bill to Name   Date
0     James Doe  41929
1      Jane Doe  41852
2  Adam Adamson  42244
3  Adam Adamson  41529

result = df.groupby('Bill to Name').agg(lambda x: max(x) - min(x))

print(result)
               Date
Bill to Name       
Adam Adamson    715
James Doe         0
Jane Doe          0
```

Comment: Can this be done without manually typing the data into the data frame?  I have a file with thousands of records.

Comment: @hohum - yes - pandas has functionality which will read your CSV document into a DataFrame: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @hohum you could do that with [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `sep` equal to what your separation (by default `,`)

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it.   Mind you, it's a bit more complex as I wrote a binary search for finding the duplicates in case you are dealing with a very large file.  I also used an index to build the list of dates for each name.

import csv
    index = []
    input_file = 'input.csv'
    output_file = 'output.csv'

```
def find_name(index, name):
    """ Binary search to see if the name exist in the index, yet. """
    if len(index) == 0:
        return -1
    start = 0
    limit = len(index) - 1
    while start <= limit:
        guess = (start + limit) / 2
        if index[guess][0] == name:
            return guess
        elif index[guess][0] < name:
            start = guess + 1
        else:
            limit = guess - 1
    return -1

def add_to_index(index, name, date):
    """ sorts the existing index.   Sends the variables to "find_name".
        if the name is round, returns the address of the name in the list.
        if it's not found, it returns a -1. """
    index.sort()
    name_index = find_name(index, name)
    if name_index == -1:
        index.append([name, [date]])
    else:
        index[name_index][1].append(date)


""" Read throught each row of the input file, skipping the header. 
    send each row to the "add_to_index" function."""
with open( input_file, 'rb' ) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header
    for row in reader:
        add_to_index(index, row[0], row[1])

""" Write the output from the index back to the output file, only
    showing writing the earliest date for each user. """
with open( output_file, 'wb' ) as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for e in index:
        name = e[0]
        e[1].sort()
        days = int(e[1][-1]) - int(e[1][0])
        writer.writerow([name, days])
```

So...  Ultimately, this builds a data structure that looks like this:

```
[[name, [date, date, date]], [name, [date, date]]
```

The names are unique and then a list of dates are associate with each unique name.   To get the difference, I just sorted the date element and subtracted the first element [0] from the last element [-1]  I hope this make sense, but it definitely creates the file correctly in my testing.

The output file looks like this:

```
Adam Adamson    715
James Doe       0
Jane Doe        0
```

Comment: I am looking for the difference between the dates, as what I am measuring is time between first and last purchases for customers to get a rough measure of tenure for a CLTV measurement.  If you replace the "max(value)-min(value)" portion of Sait's post with just "value", then you get a list in the same format you are showing.  This is more what I thought I would have to do though.

Comment: Ah... gotcha.  I'll write that variation.